# Single line sftp from terminal

Tags: unix, terminal, sftp, scp

Several times throughout the day, I may be running a test where I need to look through a log file on a remote server. I've gotten used to using my terminal to `sftp` into the remote server and pull the desired log file down to `/tmp` on my local machine.

I was looking through the options today using `man sftp` in an attempt to figure out a way to run the following commands basically in a single line so that I don't have to type a command, press enter, type a command press enter, etc.

(what I do now)

```
sftp myuser@myserver
--mypassword at prompt
lcd /tmp
get /dir/dir/dir/dir/file
quit
```

I found while looking through `man sftp` a reference to `scp` which I haven't used before. I feel it may be what I'm looking for, but I didn't see a way to specify where I wanted the securely copied file to go.

Could someone provide me with a way to get `/dir/file` from a remote server and have it download to `/tmp/file_plus-my-description`?

I was hoping to be able to run an sftp or scp command similar to a regularUNIX copy like:

```
scp myuser@myserver /dir/file /tmp/file_plus-my-description
```

I'm using the built in `Terminal` in Mac OS X 10.8. Thanks.

Comment: A related question on Super User: [Using sftp like scp](https://superuser.com/q/1434225/213663).

Answer (score 273, accepted):

**Update Sep 2017 - tl;dr**

*Download* a single file from a remote ftp server to your machine:

```
sftp {user}@{host}:{remoteFileName} {localFileName}
```

*Upload* a single file from your machine to a remote ftp server:

```
sftp {user}@{host}:{remote_dir} <<< $'put {local_file_path}'
```

---

**Original answer:**

Ok, so I feel a little dumb. But I figured it out. I almost had it at the top with:

```
sftp user@host remoteFile localFile
```

The only documentation shown in the terminal is this:

```
sftp [user@]host[:file ...]
sftp [user@]host[:dir[/]]
```

However, I came across [this site](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_sftp.htm) which shows the following under the synopsis:

```
sftp [-vC1 ] [-b batchfile ] [-o ssh_option ] [-s subsystem | sftp_server ] [-B buffer_size ] [-F ssh_config ] [-P sftp_server path ] [-R num_requests ] [-S program ] host 
sftp [[user@]host[:file [file]]] 
sftp [[user@]host[:dir[/]]]
```

So the simple answer is you just do `:` after your user and host then the remote file and local filename. Incredibly simple!

Single line, sftp copy remote file:

```
sftp username@hostname:remoteFileName localFileName
sftp kyle@kylesserver:/tmp/myLogFile.log /tmp/fileNameToUseLocally.log
```

**Update Feb 2016**

In case anyone is looking for the command to do the reverse of this and *push* a file from your local computer to a remote server in one single line `sftp`  command, user @Thariama below posted the solution to accomplish that. Hat tip to them for the extra code.

```
sftp {user}@{host}:{remote_dir} <<< $'put {local_file_path}'
```

Comment: is there a way to copy the file in one single line?

Comment: @Thariama I'm not sure what you are asking. The code above shows you how to copy a file from a remote server using sftp to your local machine in one single line. `sftp kyle@kylesserver:/tmp/myLogFile.log /tmp/fileNameToUseLocally.log`

Comment: i was asking the other way around (copy to remote server), but i found it myself: _sftp {user}@{host}:{dir} <<< $'put {path to file}'_

Comment: My apologies, misunderstood. I'll copy your response into the answer in case it can help someone in the future. Thanks @Thariama

Comment: To complete @Thariama answer, if you want to move to a directory before uploading the file write each command separate by '\n'; ```sftp {user}@{host}:{dir} <<< $'cd web\n put my_file.txt'```

Comment: For us TL:DR -types, it's a bit confusing to have the incorrect solution as the first highlighted row :-)

Comment: @Kyle, much better!

Comment: Why did you use a different syntax for user & host name? username@hostname vs {user}@{host}

Comment: The second example was provided in the comments by user @Thariama several months after the original post. I just added the data to the original post. No reason, just an oversight. Both seemed to get the point across.

Comment: I find it bizarre that sftp doesn't include an option for uploading a file in a single command. This works fine, but it's much too hacky for such a simple operation. It's still the only thing I can find that actually works out of the box, so thanks. :)

Comment: sftp {user}@{host}:{remote_dir} <<< $'put {local_file_path}' only worked on Windows using git bash. Errors shown using '<<<' on command prompt.

Comment: could you please explain `$'put {local_file_path}'`. i never seen command like that.`$(some command)` is common.@Kyle

Comment: @HosseinVatani it is essentially it's own separate command which is pushed into the sftp and executed after the connection is established.

Comment: @HosseinVatani the explanation by Kyle is confusing. It is a normal string `'put ...'` would normally work the same. The `$` at the beginning says that backslash sequences inside the string (like `\n`) will be replaced by special characters (like LF - newline). You need it to separate multiple commands for `sftp`. --- `<<<` is here string redirection which sends the following string to the `stdin` of the command (here `sftp`). --- Both are not part of the POSIX shell! They are extensions for example in bash. IMHO this should be added to the answer.

Comment: I started to use this `sftp` syntax and I have to add that it is much more similar to the `scp` syntax than the answer suggests. So not only the `user@` part can be omitted when not needed (e.g. specified inside `~/.ssh/config` but also the destination name can be a directory. In such a case the remote file si copied with the original file name to the local directory. I think most of the time I will use `.` as the destination.

Comment: Won't work as you're not giving password.

Comment: @PhilipRego if you don't enter a password, the system will prompt you for a password following your command. Often you don't want to include the password within your command, because you don't want to be leaving passwords laying around in shell command history.

Comment: I want it in the command because sftp is not accepting my password. Works fine in WinSCP but failing with sftp command. No special characters.

Answer (score 14):

#### SCP answer

The OP mentioned SCP, so here's that.

As others have pointed out, SFTP is a confusing since the *upload* syntax is completely different from the *download* syntax. It gets *marginally* easier to remember if you use the same form:

```
echo 'put LOCALPATH REMOTEPATH' | sftp USER@HOST
echo 'get REMOTEPATH LOCALPATH' | sftp USER@HOST
```

In reality, this is still a mess, and is why people still use "outdated" commands such as SCP:

```
scp USER@HOST:REMOTEPATH LOCALPATH
scp LOCALPATH USER@HOST:REMOTEPATH
```

SCP is secure but dated. It has some bugs that will never be fixed, namely crashing if the server's `.bash_profile` emits a message. However, in terms of usability, the devs were years ahead.

Answer (score 7):

To UPLOAD a single file, you will need to create a bash script. Something like the following should work on OS X if you have `sshpass` installed.

Usage:

```
sftpx <password> <user@hostname> <localfile> <remotefile>
```

Put this script somewhere in your path and call it `sftpx`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export RND=`cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 32`
export TMPDIR=/tmp/$RND
export FILENAME=$(basename "$4")
export DSTDIR=$(dirname "$4")

mkdir $TMPDIR
cp "$3" $TMPDIR/$FILENAME

export SSHPASS=$1
sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - $2 << !
   lcd $TMPDIR
   cd $DSTDIR
   put $FILENAME
   bye
!

rm $TMPDIR/$FILENAME
rmdir $TMPDIR
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, the answer I denoted above will utilize single line command with sftp to get a file from a remote server and save the file to a specific location on your local machine. I have verified that it will work on OS X with only sftp.

Comment: Yes, that is certainly the best answer for transferring from remote to local. However I though I'd add a solution for doing the opposite: local to remote. Just in case it's helpful to anyone. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

OpenSSH `scp` [supports SFTP protocol since 8.7](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7).

Since [OpenSSH 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0) the `scp` uses SFTP by default.

In 8.7 through 8.9, the SFTP has to be selected via `-s` parameter.

Download:

```
scp -s user@host:/remote/source/path /local/target/path
```

Upload:

```
scp -s /local/source/path user@host:/remote/target/path
```

Answer (score 5):

Or  `echo 'put {path to file}' | sftp {user}@{host}:{dir}`, which would work in both unix and powershell.

Comment: This syntax also works with puttyftp (psftp). Just thought I’d share since that’s the reason I ended up here

Answer (score 3):

sftp supports batch files.

From the man page:

```
-b batchfile

Batch mode reads a series of commands from an input batchfile instead of stdin.  
Since it lacks user interaction it should be used in conjunction with non-interactive
authentication.  A batchfile of `-' may be used to indicate standard input.  sftp 
will abort if any of the following commands fail: get, put, rename, ln, rm, mkdir, 
chdir, ls, lchdir, chmod, chown, chgrp, lpwd, df, symlink, and lmkdir.  Termination 
on error can be suppressed on a command by command basis by prefixing the command 
with a `-' character (for example, -rm /tmp/blah*).
```

Comment: As this is a process I do several times a day for different files in different places, it would be nice to be able to just memorize a command I could type into a single line in my terminal (which is always open) and press enter. Using `--batch` would require me to put my commands into a file then pass in that file as a param. I'm still playing with `scp`, I feel it may contain my solution.

Comment: Maybe 'expect' is what you're looking for then. http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3065

Answer (score 2):

A minor modification like below worked for me when using it from within perl and system() call:

```
sftp {user}@{host} <<< $'put {local_file_path} {remote_file_path}'
```