# How can i upload file by command line via sftp?

Tags: linux, bash, file-upload, command-line, sftp

I know how to get remote file via sftp.

ex:

```
sftp root@10.0.0.1:/path/to/file.txt localfile.txt
```

How can i upload file to remote server?

(I need use this command in my bash script.)

Comment: sftp CANT upload file.

Comment: scp /local/file.txt root@10.0.0.1:/remote/file.txt

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16723151/2148773 (the "Update Feb 2016" section).

Answer (score -5, accepted):

```
$ scp root@10.0.0.1:/path/to/file.txt localfile.txt
```

Comment: Ive tried the scp command. It works. Thanks so much!

Comment: This won't work if the service allows SFTP connections only (ie, disallows logging in via SSH).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. SFTP is something different to SCP. The 5 upvotes come obvoisly from people who run SSH and SFTP servers on the same server.

Comment: This is not an answer - the question was using SFTP ... not SCP

Comment: looking for sftp, not scp

Comment: Warning, see @ss-t.c 's comment above. If you are trying to upload a file, this will fail (if the remote file does not exist) or download the file instead!

Comment: yeah~~ this answer can upload the file in most situations. because most server allow login vis ssh. If you wanna do a real sftp upload see @oliver 's comment above. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16723151/2148773)

Answer (score 1):

Also think about using SSH public/private keys which can avoid you to have to enter a password for your automated file exchanges.

You can use the command "ssh-keygen" to generate those keys.

Comment: I've generate the ssh-key. Thanks!