# SFTP inline put without interaction

Tags: command-line, sftp, scp, chroot

I am trying to automate an application deployment as part of this I need to upload a file to a server. I have created a minimal user and configured chroot for the SFTP server but I can't work out how to upload a file non interactive.

At present I am doing `scp myfile buildUser@myserver.com:newBuilds/`

I tried `sftp buildUser@myserver.com myfile` (`newBuilds` is the chroot dir) but this didn't upload anything but it did connect.

The reason for favouring this aproach and NOT using `scp` is that its a lot more difficult to restrict scp access (from the information I have learned).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using OpenSSH server, chrooting works for both SCP and SFTP.

For instructions see:
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/chroot-users-with-openssh-an-easier-way-to-confine-users-to-their-home-directories/

So I believe your question is irrelevant.

---

Anyway, `sftp` (assuming OpenSSH) is not really designed for command-line-only upload. You typically use `-b` switch to specify batch file with `put` command.

```
sftp buildUser@myserver.com -b batchfile
```

With `batchfile` containing:

```
put /local/path /remote/path
```

If you really need command-line-only upload, see:

- [Single line sftp from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16721891/850848) or
- [Using sftp like scp](https://superuser.com/q/1434225/213663)

So basically, you can use various forms of input redirection like:

```
sftp buildUser@myserver.com <<< 'put /local/path /remote/path'
```

- Or simply use [`scp`](https://man.openbsd.org/scp), instead of `sftp`. Most servers support both. And actually OpenSSH `scp` [supports SFTP protocol since 8.7](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7).
  Since [OpenSSH 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0) it even uses SFTP by default. In 8.7 through 8.9, the SFTP has to be selected via `-s` parameter. See my answer to already mentioned [Single line sftp from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16721891/850848#68701143).

Answer (score 5):

You can pass inline commands to SFTP like this:

```
sftp -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@host <<END
lcd /path/to/local/dir
cd /path/to/remote/dir
put file
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by approaching it from a different side. I tried configuring `chroot` for `sftp` but could not get this to work. My solution was to use `rssh` and only allow `scp`. This works for me because the user I am trying to restrict is known and authenticated user.