# Restore an online SQL Server database with a local .bak file via cmd panel

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've developed an Android app that uses an online SQL Server database (hosting provider is: a2hosting.com).

In addition, there is a native Windows app that everyday at 12am backup some tables in a `.bak` file in `E:\` location (USB FLASH DRIVE location).

I want to make a scheduled cmd batch file to update the server database with the local database.

I am trying to use the restore command to do that, because I want to replace the previous online database with my new local database.

What I have try to do:

`restoreTOdb.bat` file:

```
sqlcmd -S (myservername) -U (myusername) -P (mypassword) -i db.sql

pause
```

`db.sql` file:

```
USE master;
GO

RESTORE DATABASE (mydbname) 
FROM DISK = 'E:\filename.bak' 
WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, NORECOVERY, STATS = 5;
GO
```

The connection to my SQL Server database is successful

This is the error that appears in cmd:

> Changed database context to 'master'.
>
> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Server (server-name), Line 1
>   Cannot open backup device 'E:\filename.bak'.
>
> Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server (server-name), Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>
> C:\Users\Manos\Desktop\DB CONNECTION>pause

Comment: I noticed you are using the E drive, is that a removable device? If so than its only mounted for your windows shell and therefore the MsSQL server that's trying to load it can't see it. Copy it to a physical hard drive, like C, that the MsSQL server can see and It will probably work! It is a non-intuitive behavior of windows, especially for those used to posix OS servers.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear it needs to be copied to the C drive of the machine running the MsSQL server.

Comment: @RalphRitoch Thank you for your answer, i tried in D:, C: and E: drive every time the same error.

Comment: did you copy it to the C/D of the server, such as via sftp or some other file transfer method? The remote server can't see your local drives, normally.

Comment: If you want to restore a `.bak` onto a **remote** server machine, the `*.bak` file **must be** on that **remote machine's E:** drive...... the remote SQL Server cannot reach down and grab a file off your local E:\ drive (**thank goodness** it can't do that!!)

Comment: @RalphRitoch ah i didn't know that. Can you explain me, how to use the sftp command? The only command that i know is ftp but i had no success with this script so i abandoned it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721891/single-line-sftp-from-terminal

Comment: @marc_s thank you very much for your explanation. I will try to send my .bak file first in my online file server and then i will try to use it.

Comment: @RalphRitoch Really thank you for your help, i will study this command. I didn't know about it.